# "Failed to open indexedDB" error in Firefox when trying to get record from IndexedDB using PouchDB

Tags: indexeddb, pouchdb

I've build a simple system that allows a person to add a note for a webpage. This works flawlessly for Chrome (Version 72.0.3626.109) but when in Firefox (Version 65.0.1) it is giving me an error in the developer console.

```
error: true
​message: "unknown"
​name: "indexed_db_went_bad"
​reason: "Failed to open indexedDB, are you in private browsing mode?"
​stack: ""
​status: 500
​<prototype>: {…}
```

Debugging this in the Firefox dev console the error is thrown when attempting the `get` call in this javascript function:

```
function pouchDbGetNote() {
        notesDb.get(notesData.noteDbEntryId)
            .then(function (response) {
                returnNoteData(response);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Please note that when the page is loaded, just prior to the `pouchDbGetNote()` function is called I load the DB via the following:

```
// Create/get database
    try {
        notesDb = new PouchDB(notesData.db_name);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    pouchDbGetNote();
```

I've dug around in google and have found no real solution other than suggestions that its fixed with a Firefox upgrade and hints that this used to affect IE/Edge also.

The call above is held within a `jQuery(document).ready(function () {` block.

Comment: Does PouchDB's implementation handle connection blocked events?

Answer (score 0):

Set the browser's privacy & security settings to remember history